# axios.post() doesn't get any response

Tags: ajax, post, axios

I am using laravel 5.6 and vue.js. While sending ajax post request to login:

```
<script>

    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {

        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },

        data(){
            return {
                email: '',
                password: '',
                remember: false
            }

        },

        computed: {

            validateFields(){...}
        },

        created: function(){
            axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        },

        methods: {

            validateEmail(){...},

            attemptLogin(){

                axios.post('/login', {

                        email: this.email,
                        password: this.password,
                        remember: this.remember

                    }).then(resp => {

                        console.log(resp)
                    }).catch(error => {

                        console.log(error.mesage)
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I don't get any response, though while debugging I see that request has correct data ([request with data, but not response])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qFES.png)
CSRF is enabled on the app, but it is included in the layout header :
`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` and axios registers it automatically. What might be the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Where do you call attemptLogin() ?

Comment: It is callled on onClick method of Log in button. It all works fine here, I debugged it, the request is sent and the data is correct, I have no idea why doesn't it work on serverside. Maybe wrong format or additional security measures :( , as far as I know it should work like this. Waiting for any suggestions should you have, thank you.